# Роутер бьет соединение?

Tags: роутер

Есть роутер NETGEAR WGR614-900RUSЕсли подключаться по шнурку напрямую к пк, скорость где-то 70 000 кбитсек : http://internet.yandex.ru/informer/horizontal/73208-62522.png

Если подключаться через вай фай роутер, то скорость значительно ниже:http://internet.yandex.ru/informer/horizontal/15608-18729.png

Скорость через роутер всегда такая же, не важно сколько пк в нагрузке, один или 4.

Вопрос такой, это роутер больше не пропускает? Или вай фай больше не может взять на ноуте?Или роутер делит соединение на всех? Почему тогда когда я один, скорость все равно меньше?

Как быть, чтобы использовать максимум?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю поможет это http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi

и это http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/100BASE-T

т. е. вайфай на данном роутере не может больше

Хотя есть ещё предположение, если выбранная частота зашумлена, то есть смысл попробовать поискать более "чистый" канал (в настройках вайфая на роутере)

Меняете канал на другой, реконнект ноута, спидтест... и так далее, пока не найдётся более быстрый.

NETGEAR WGR614-900RUS поддерживает 802.11g (54 Мбит/с), так что нужно учитывать, что больше этой скорости никак не получится.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете посоветовать роутер, который обладает более мощной пропускной способностью?

Comment: Да, по шнурку скорость значительно выше. Если два пк подключены по шнурку, он бьет примерно по 25 мбит\сек канал. Т.е. поровну на каждый пк, верно? (объявленная скорость провайдера 50 мбит\сек)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не совсем в роутере. Это архитектура wifi 11g такова, что средний максимум около 22мбит. И больше вы не получите ни с одним роутером с протоколом 11g. Смотрите в сторону роутеров поддерживающих 802.11n.